# center image inside a container

Tags: html, css

In this article I have three images that I want to be placed in the same line. The first image should go to the left, the second should be centered and the third will be placed to the right.

I have no problems with the first one and with the third one since doing a float:left or float:right in CSS I solve it but I can not get the second image to center.

```
<section>
     <article>
         <img class="first" src="img/1.jpg" alt="img"/>
         <img class="second" src="img/2.jpg" alt="img"/>
         <img class="third" src="img/3.jpg" alt="img"/>
     </article>
 </section>
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

```css
article {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<section>
     <article>
         <img class="first" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="img"/>
         <img class="second" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="img"/>
         <img class="third" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="img"/>
     </article>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```
<div class='flexWrapper'>
    <img class="first" src="img/1.jpg" alt="img"/>
    <img class="second" src="img/2.jpg" alt="img"/>
    <img class="third" src="img/3.jpg" alt="img"/>
</div>

.flexWrapper {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center; /* to align them vertically */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can used flexbox.

```css
article {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<section>
     <article>        
         <img class="first" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="img"/>
         <img class="second" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="img"/>
         <img class="third" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="img"/>
     </article>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

hello there!

```
<section>
          <article>
          <img class="first" src="img/1.jpg" alt="img"/>
          <img class="second center" src="img/2.jpg" alt="img"/>
          <img class="third" src="img/3.jpg" alt="img"/>
         </article>
       </section>
```

use this css class

```
    .center {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 50%;
    }
```

now try to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

finally I solved it by indicating text-align: center in css of the article. It works because the images, like the text, are line elements.
Thank you